# Talend dbinput step error : The server principal "SQL-USER" is not able to access the database "DATABASE-1" under the current security context

Tags: sql-server, database, etl, talend

I'm using Talend Data Studio v7.1.1. In the DbInput step I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server Database. The Db connection works as excepted, I have tested this with DBVisualizer and also the tDB_connection step in Talend. This is my Talend job:

[image]

Running the job I get the following error message in DbInput step:

```
[FATAL]: dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner - tDBInput_1 The server principal "SQL-USER" is not able to access the database "DATABASE-1" under the current security context.
java.sql.SQLException: The server principal  "SQL-USER"  is not able to access the database "DATABASE-1" under the current security context.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1427)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.tDBInput_1Process(raw_co_planner.java:7017)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.tDBConnection_2Process(raw_co_planner.java:6818)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.tDBConnection_1Process(raw_co_planner.java:6573)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.tJava_2Process(raw_co_planner.java:6278)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.tJava_1Process(raw_co_planner.java:6068)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.runJobInTOS(raw_co_planner.java:8383)
    at dwh_etl.raw_co_planner_1_1.raw_co_planner.main(raw_co_planner.java:7250)
```

What's strange with this error is that I am **NOT** trying to access **DATABASE-1** anywhere in my job and configuration. I use another database i.e. DATABASE-2 and specify this specifically in database connection settings in tDbInput step. DATABASE-1 and DATABASE-2 are part of the same SQL Server conenction and **SQL-USER** have complete privileges **ONLY** to DATABASE-2.

I have repeated testing with both Built-in and repository settings in DBInput step. Also tried setting context variables for the database but it didn't resolve the issue. I have checked this topic in Stack Overflow and none of the questions are related to Talend where the error is pointing to a different database.

Comment: *Something* is trying to access the other database. What is `tDBInput_1` doing? Is it, for example, `INSERT`ing into a table and that table has a `TRIGGER` that references an object in the database `Database-1`?

Comment: Just a guess, maybe your user has default database set to Database-1? check select dbname,* from sys.syslogins
where name = 'SQL-USER'

Comment: @ThomA. There is nothing configured to access the other database from talend side. tDBInput_1 just reads the connections and runs a select query on it. No, it doesn't inserts data.

Comment: @siggemannen No I have checked this and DATABASE-2 is set as default

Comment: What is the object it's running against? Is it a `VIEW`? Is it a table with a computed column that uses a user defined function? Just because *you* aren't accessing the other database *explicitly* doesn't mean what you are doing isn't.

Comment: I'd suggest, first, connecting to the SQL host directly with the credentials you use in Talend and trying to replicate the error. If you can't, then the problem is in Talend. If you can, then start looking at the definitions of the objects you are referencing.

Comment: seems like the database can be connected from another SQL tool but query gives the same error message. Thanks @ThomA. DBA team is looking into it. I'll post if we find a solution

Comment: Aside... jTDS hasn't had a release in very nearly ten years. Why are you still using that?